# formatando uma string com str_pad

Tags: php

Galera com a ajuda do pessoal aqui do stack, eu montei um função onde faço o tratamento de uma string.

Vou postar o código e explicar o problema.

Função:

```
function mb_str_pad($input, $pad_length, $pad_string = ' ', $pad_type =    STR_PAD_RIGHT, $encoding = "UTF-8") {
$diff = strlen($input) - mb_strlen($input, $encoding);
return str_pad($input, $pad_length + $diff, $pad_string, $pad_type);
}
```

Exemplo, quando eu chamo a função assim:

```
echo mb_str_pad("ESPERANÇA", 15, "#");
```

Ela me retorna:

```
ESPERANÇA######
```

Bom o problema começa quando coloca uma palavra que contenha mais de 15 letras, preciso que ela corte a palavra. 
Exemplo de como deve ficar:

```
echo mb_str_pad("ESPERANÇAaaaaaaaaaaa", 15, "#");
```

Tem que retornar assim:

```
ESPERANÇAaaaaaa
```

Ou seja se passar de 15 caracter ele tem que cortar e ignorar tudo que estiver a direita.

Alguém pode me ajudar com isso?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usa o strlen para pegar o tamanho e o substr para determinar o inicio e fim da string

```html
<?php

function mb_str_pad($input, $pad_length, $pad_string = ' ', $pad_type =    STR_PAD_RIGHT, $encoding = "UTF-8") {
$diff = strlen($input) - mb_strlen($input, $encoding);
$str = str_pad($input, $pad_length + $diff, $pad_string, $pad_type);
$tam = strlen ( $str );
return ($tam > 15 ) ? substr($str, 0, 15) : $str;
}

echo mb_str_pad("ESPERANÇAaaaaaaaaaaa", 15, "#");
?>
```

Comment: Bom dessa forma quase deu certo,  porem preciso capturar o valor que eu passo quando eu chamo a função `mb_str_pad` pois em cada lugar que eu chamo ela, ele possui um valor diferente.

Comment: blz coloquei assim `substr($str, 0, $pad_length);`

Comment: Bom, fico feliz em ter ajudado de alguma forma. :)

Answer (score 4):

Utilizando a função [substr](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.substr.php), você passa três parâmetros: A string a ser cortada, a posição de início e a quantidade de caracteres a serem cortados.

```
function mb_str_pad($input, $pad_length, $pad_string = ' ', $pad_type =    STR_PAD_RIGHT, $encoding = "UTF-8") {
    $diff = strlen($input) - mb_strlen($input, $encoding);
    return substr(str_pad($input, $pad_length + $diff, $pad_string, $pad_type),0,15);
}

echo mb_str_pad("ESPERANÇAaaaaaaaaaaa", 15, "#");
```

Veja funcionando no [ideone](http://ideone.com/Zc8HSA)